# Java SWT: MouseTrackListener only fires events when the shell is focused

Tags: java, focus, swt, mouseevent

I've got a `Shell` with an attached `MouseTrackListener`.

When the shell has focus, the events of the `MouseTrackListener` work fine, but when I select another application and the shell no longer has focus, the `mouseEnter` and `mouseExit` events no longer fire.

How do I remedy this problem? I know it is possible, since it worked in a Swing implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it is possible, since it worked in a Swing implementation.

You can't really say that, since SWT uses native OS widgets, whereas Swing doesn't. So their behaviour doesn't have to be the same.

---

You problem is definitely OS dependent. When using Windows (not necessarily SWT, use anything) and scrolling over a window that doesn't have the focus, the content doesn't scroll. When doing the same in Linux, the content does scroll.

I just tested code on Linux that uses a `MouseTrackListener` and it is fired even if the window/`Shell` doesn't have focus.

---

Concluding, I'm afraid there is nothing you can do.

Comment: I meant "I know it is possible" in the sense that the writer of SWT could get it to work. Ah well. Thanks for the closure.

Comment: @SuperDisk Since SWT is based on OS widgets, they can't just make it work. The fact that it works in Swing is because they use custom widgets.